# Fail to serve .jsp and .html file via default servlet handler using spring mvc <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, static-resource

The title should explain the biggest part :)

I should be able for example to access http://www.someurl.com:8080/index.jsp but instead I get HTTP Status 404 - /index.jsp

Now why do I assume I should be able to serve static content (ie not be redirected to custom controller but to default servlet handler in stead.)?
Because I have added the following element to my mvc dispatcher servlet config:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

I have read that in some case the name of the default server cannot be guessed and I have looked it up in the file: ̣*~/tomcat7/conf/web.xml .*
The default servlet is specified by a name "default". So I tried adding:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="default"/>
```

But to no avail...

- I have one spring dispachter servlet mapped to '/'.
- I have two controllers mapped to, one controller is mapped to '/' and one is mapped to '/todo'
  The controllers work fine.

I thought the controller mapped to '/' could be the culprit so I removed that controller but to no avail.
Anybody an idea? And is it possible to have a controller mapped to '/' and still serve a page like /index.jsp??

Answer (score 0):

Arf, I had put my static resources under the webapp/WEB-INF folder instead of the webapp folder. Now it seems te be working fine ... :)